# Show overflow:hidden DIVS on click

Tags: jquery

I have seen similar questions posted here but I can't seem to find the right one for my desired approach.  Probably cause I have minimal knowledge on jQuery.

Basically this is the case.  I have a page containing 10 DIVS, say #page1 to #page10.  I set overflow to hidden so only the first DIV, #page1 is shown on viewport.  Is there a way to show the consecutive next and previous DIV on click .. say to have a "previous" and "next" link somewhere?

*edit*

My original idea was to have DIV overflow hidden and scroll to the DIV but found that the solution given by @Steve is what I needed.  For overflow hidden solution, a method was explained by @VisioN.

Comment: Overflow hidden or display hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you said overflow:hidden.....  Do you actually mean Visibilily:hidden or Display:none?

I've made a example using display none.

http://jsfiddle.net/4HpXz/4/

Doesn't currently handle when you click "next" on already the last div but you could either hide the next link or make it clever enough to not hide the last div if you click next for example

JS

```
$(function(){

    $('.next').click(function(){
        $('.page.show')
            .removeClass('show')
            .next()
            .addClass('show');   
    });

    $('.prev').click(function(){
        $('.page.show')
            .removeClass('show')
            .prev()
            .addClass('show');   
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="page show">Page1</div>
<div class="page">Page2</div>
<div class="page">Page3</div>
<div class="page">Page4</div>
<div class="page">Page5</div>
<div class="page">Page6</div>
<div class="page">Page7</div>
<div class="page">Page8</div>
<div class="page">Page9</div>
<div class="page">Page10</div>​
```

CSS

```
.page{
    display: none;
}
.show{
    display: block;
}
​
```

Comment: This method currently uses a class "show" to indercate the currently visible div. but if you didnt want to do this you could selet it with a  more complex selector that will look for a div with a display of "NOT BLOCK"

Comment: This was not my original approach but it seems to fit what I want to achieve.  I will give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: I have tried and seems like it works out well.  However, is there a way to prevent last page from going further  The simplest solution is probably to remove the "next" link but I am just interested to know if it's possible that even if user click "next" on the last page, the page will remain as last page.

Comment: A simple wrap of the logic to check that there is indeed a next (or prev) item with the correct class! http://jsfiddle.net/4HpXz/5/

Also example with divs maintaining there position http://jsfiddle.net/4HpXz/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can make slide effect to those div.

For example:

```
var firstpage = $('#container div#page1'), 
      pgwidth = firstpage.outerWidth();

$('.prevButton').on('click', function() {
  firstpage.animate({
     'margin-left' : '-=' + pgwidth + 'px' // sliding the first div amount of its outerWidth to left
  },300);
});


$('.prevButton').on('click', function() {
  firstpage.animate({
     'margin-left' : '+=' + pgwidth + 'px' // sliding the first div amount of its outerWidth to right
  },300);
});
```

Comment: So I have tried your method.  It works but when I slide to the next DIV and slide back, it doesn't allow me to slide forward anymore .. any solution to this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood correctly, you need to have a look at [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) method.

As you get from the title it scrolls the element into view. It is quite basic and is supported even by IE6.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8D2jB/

Comment: Thanks! I tried all the solutions and it seemed Steve's approach is closest to what I need.

Comment: OK. However, if you need to show elements that are out of viewport in `overflow: hidden` block then this method makes sense.